# Unable to update IAM policy in AI Platform Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I can't update IAM policy in my AI Platform Notebook.

I created a new AI Platform Notebooks instance:

```sh
gcloud beta notebooks instances create nb1 \
 --vm-image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
 --vm-image-family=tf-latest-cpu \
 --machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
 --location=us-west1-b
```

When I try to apply a new IAM policy I get an Error:

```
gcloud beta notebooks instances set-iam-policy nb1 --location=us-west1-b notebooks.policy
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.notebooks.instances.set-iam-policy) INTERNAL: An
>   internal error has occurred (506011f7-b62e-4308-9bde-10b97dd7b99c)

My policy looks like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:myuser@gmail.com",   
      ],
      "role": "roles/notebooks.admin"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "BwWlgdvxWT0=",
  "version": 1
}
```

when I do a

```sh
gcloud beta notebooks instances get-iam-policy nb1 --location=us-west1-b --format=json
```

I get:

```
ACAB
```

As there is no policy set.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at etag field:

*An etag is returned in the response to getIamPolicy, and systems are expected to put that etag in the request to setIamPolicy to ensure that their change will be applied to the same version of the policy.*

From documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy)

```
string (bytes format)

etag is used for optimistic concurrency control as a way to help prevent simultaneous updates of a policy from overwriting each other. It is strongly suggested that systems make use of the etag in the read-modify-write cycle to perform policy updates in order to avoid race conditions: An etag is returned in the response to getIamPolicy, and systems are expected to put that etag in the request to setIamPolicy to ensure that their change will be applied to the same version of the policy.

Important: If you use IAM Conditions, you must include the etag field whenever you call setIamPolicy. If you omit this field, then IAM allows you to overwrite a version 3 policy with a version 1 policy, and all of the conditions in the version 3 policy are lost.

A base64-encoded string.
```

You can just easily change your policy etag to ACAB, which is the default one.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:myuser@gmail.com",   
      ],
      "role": "roles/notebooks.admin"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "ACAB",
  "version": 1
}
```

or you can use [add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/notebooks/instances/add-iam-policy-binding) command, to create a new policy, then you can extract the etag using `get-iam-policy` and update your JSON file with it, finally run the `set-iam-policy`

You may also use this format:

```
{
  "policy": {
    "bindings": [
        {
          "members": [
            "user:myuser@gmail.com"
          ],
          "role": "roles/notebooks.admin"
        }
      ],
      "etag": "ACAB",
      "version": 1
    }
}
```